# Stuck on Commissioning Nodes through MaaS

Tags: maas, pxe, ipmi

I've been working with MaaS attempting to commission a set of nodes through a dual switch setup (Private & Public) using iDRAC with IPMI in attempts to PXE boot them, yet cannot seem to get it to work.

Within MaaS under events, the node seems to get stuck in a loop that states: "Queried node's BMC - Power State queried: on" until the commissioning process times out after 20 minutes. I've enabled DHCP under the subnet "InteriorSwitchFabric" and set its reserved ranges (192.168.1.191-254). I've also enabled IPMI under the iDRAC interface.

Within the MaaS log file, I get the same error listed above as well as "Failed to change the boot order to PXE 192.168.1.xxx: /usr/sbin/ipmi-config: connection timeout."

Keep in mind that the two management nodes are on the administrative private network (192.168.1.0/24), while the 14 sub nodes are on the public network (10.10.133.0/24). I've linked the relevant screenshots below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Node Event Log Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHTZA.png)

[Node Storage Tab, If Useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyAk6.png)

[Node Interfaces Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA5sY.png)

[MaaS Log Trial 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMiEg.jpg)

[MaaS Log Trial 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtEMY.jpg)

[PXE Boot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv2mx.jpg)

Comment: You have two network interfaces attached to the same subnet on the same VLAN on the same fabric. How is it supposed to work without ARP configuration?

Comment: Ah, I see you might be onto something. How might one configure ARP for MaaS to effectively commission these nodes?

Comment: You shouldn't attach them to the same subnet on the same VLAN on the same fabric.